# Apache PHP project root handler / front controller pattern

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

I'm running Apache 2.4 locally using php. My goal is each time I make a request it will link to the root of the project folder, `http://localhost/project_root/`

For example:

`http://localhost/project_root/` is requested and links to `http://localhost/project_root/index.php`

a second example:

`http://localhost/project_root/foo/bar` would link to `http://localhost/project_root/index.php`

Where the final idea is that `http://localhost/project_root/index.php` handles redirections and loading of resources.

Thanks in advance and any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: ok, but i don't see a question here?

Comment: It appears he is trying to make a model view controller framework using php. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this sort of thing I place an `.htaccess` file in the root of the application:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  #Optional: Only if it's not a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  #Only if it's not a valid file
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This passes in the remaining portion of the url as `$_GET['q']`, and preserves any other parameters as well.

You'll need to make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled in Apache, and AllowOverride is set to `all` in your sites-enabled.

Comment: People tend to use `$_GET['q'];` while using `mod_rewrite` like this. Just a tip.

Comment: Roger that.  Answer adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is to implement a front controller
http://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/

To do so you need to use mod_rewrite to force all .php requests to go to your front controller.

The following can go in your .htaccess or apache config (httpd.conf)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project_root/index.php
```

Comment: Perfect.
**index.php** may use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to know initially requested URL.

Comment: Awesome link man thanks Ill try it out and the htaccess code does not work me for however.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use mod_rewrite to implement a *front-controller pattern*, as suggested in the other answers. Apache mod_dir provides the `FallbackResource` directive. For example:

```
FallbackResource /project_root/index.php
```

This states that for any request that would normally trigger a "404 Not Found", internally rewrite the request to `/project_root/index.php` instead.

This is equivalent to the [mod_rewrite solution in @rmcfrazier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23418160/369434).

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource