# Routing system only recognising homepage

Tags: php, model-view-controller, url-routing, router

I have been building a simple MVC Framework in PHP, when I try to access different urls only the home route works. I tried debugging and only discovered that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns / or page not found. Everything seems okay to me. I will post the router class and controller  below and how it is implemented.Any response and help will be greatly appreciated.Bitbucket to full url has been attached[text](https://bitbucket.org/kapasulediesel5/commerce/src/main/)

```
class Router
{
    private array $handlers = [];

    public function get(string $path, $handler): void
    {
        $this->addHandler('GET', $path, $handler);
    }

    public function post(string $path, $handler): void
    {
        $this->addHandler('POST', $path, $handler);
    }

    private function addHandler(string $method, string $path, $handler): void
    {
        $this->handlers[] = [
            'path' => $path,
            'method' => $method,
            'handler' => $handler
        ];
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $requestUri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $requestPath = $requestUri['path'];
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        $callBack = null;
        foreach ($this->handlers as $handler) {
            if ($handler['path'] === $requestPath && $method === $handler['method']) {
                $callBack = $handler['handler'];
            }
        }

        if (!$callBack) {
            $response = new Response();
            return $response->setStatusCode(404);
        }


        if (is_string($callBack)) {
            $parts = explode('::', $callBack);
            if (is_array($parts)) {
                $className = array_shift($parts);
                $handler = new $className;
                $method = array_shift($parts);

                $callBack = [$handler,$method];
            }
        }


        call_user_func_array($callBack, [
            array_merge($_POST, $_GET)

        ]);
    }
}
```

```
$router = new Router();

$router->get('/', ProductsController::class . '::showProducts');

$router->get('/productlist', ProductsController::class . '::showProducts');

$router->post('/views/addproduct.php', ProductsController::class . '::create');

$router->post('/', ProductsController::class.'::deleteProduct');

$router->run();
```

```
Class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * index() returns all products from the database table.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $connection = new DBConnection();
        $product = new ProductsModel($connection);
        $products = $product->allProducts();

        return $this->loadView('productlist', [
            'products' => $products
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * addProduct adds a new product to the database table.
     *
     */
    public function create()
    {
                $connection = new DBConnection();
                $product = new ProductsModel($connection);
                
            if( $_POST['save'] ) {
                $sku = $request->input('sku');
                var_dump($sku);
                $name = $request->input('name');
                $price = $request->input('price');
                $productType = $request->input('productType');
                $weight = $request->input('weight');
                $height = $request->input('height');
                $size = $request->input('size');
                $width = $request->input('width');
                $length = $request->input('length');

                $product->addProduct($sku, $name, $price, $weight, $height, $length, $width, $size, $productType);
            }
           

        return $this->loadView('/addproduct');
    }

    /**
     * deleteProduct deletes one or more products from the database.
     */
    public function deleteProduct()
    {
        $connection = new DBConnection();
        $deleteProduct = new ProductsModel($connection);

        if (isset($_POST['button_delete'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['selectedID'])) {
                var_dump($_POST['selectedID']);
                $deleteProduct->destroyProduct($_POST['selectedID']);
            }
        }
        header('Location: https://www.techspeed.co.zw/');
    }
}
```

Comment: _"discovered that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns / or page not found"_ - I very much doubt that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] itself contains the actual text "page not found" ...? Did you do anything to let your webserver know that it should invoke your script, when you request just any arbitrary URL? Sounds like you missed to implement that very first basic step to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I once tried to use .htaccess file on the web server and didn’t work as expected. Would you care to help out if you have an idea on how to implement it on the server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23418106/1427878